# Responsive Menu, Multi-level, CSS and Javascript ONLY, no jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, menu, responsive

All,

**Using ONLY javascript and CSS**, I need to create a responsive menu. The menu must also supports one level sub-menus.

Due to the memory limitations of the embedded hardware, I cannot use external libraries/frameworks.

I have browsed as much as I could. The examples I have found don't quite address my problem.

- If the menu is responsive, it does not support sub-menus ...
- If it supports sub-menus, the submenus expand within the menus, instead of replacing them ...
- If it does everything I need, then it is in jQuery, and I cannot use it ...

I have been 'piecing' together snippets of code (http://codepen.io/vpappano/pen/NRLRWJ)

However, I am now stuck with the following problem. Because I embedded the submenu (id="myDropdown")

```
<div class="dropdown-content"  id="myDropdown">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

within the main menu (id="myTopnav"), I don't manage to display the submenu when in the minimized state.

The only solution I could come up with is to duplicate the submenu (id="myDropdown2")

```
<div class="dropdown-content"  id="myDropdown2">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

which, of course, is "so wrong on so many different levels" ...  :-)

Can you improve my code in such a way that I am using only one occurrence of the submenu? A link to a JSFiddle, CodePen, or similar would be extremely helpful ...

**Please NO jQuery**. I can only use javascript and CSS. However, if you are aware of a little js-css-only library that achieves what I am looking for (MIT license), that will also do the trick ...  :-)

Thank you so much ...

Vincenzo

Comment: sounds like you want us to code it all for you.

Comment: Anything that can be done in jQuery can be done in Vanilla JS. Just find one that does what you want in jQuery, then write something similar in Vanilla JS.

Comment: @synthet1c - What the question is really asking is .. if I only keep the submenu with "myDropdown2", how do I properly position it wrt the "Dropdown" menu ...

Comment: You have not shown what you have done to solve this problem, to give anyone a place to begin helping you.

Comment: My first option would be [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). However, if you really wan't to create that functionality, you first need to create a "concept" of every menu /submenu click and window resize scenario.
For instance, you can use "show / hide" your menu's/submenus .

Comment: @synthet1c - The whole "task" is about a responsive menu with sub-menus ... And, if you try the CodePen, you will see that the functionality has been achieved. However, as an improvement, I would like to have only one instance of the sub menu. If you are able and/or willing to help, I appreciate your time. If not, I appreciate your time as well...  :-)     BTW, greetings to the "Land From Down Under"   :-)

Comment: @Jacob, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Andre, I really love 'bootstrap' -- but I don't have enough memory one the microcontroller -- We barely manage to fit Zepto.js, which is about 10k    :-)

Comment: @Vincenzo I've added one answer with an example of how you can achieve this behavior without any libraries.

Comment: @Andre ... I had not seen this reply, but I did see, and accepted, your solution below. Thank you again ...  :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "not so simple" demo of [responsive navigation](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp) taken from w3schools, and modified by me to show a simple submenu behavior.

The most important part here to take note is that you might have to create a  function to close other submenus, when you open another one and edit the non responsive CSS.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
function openSubMenu() {
    var x = document.getElementById("submenuNav");
    if (x.hidden === true) {
        x.hidden = false;
    } else {
        x.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact"  onclick="openSubMenu()">Contact</a>
  <ul class="subnav" id="submenuNav" hidden >
      <li><a href="#contact" class="submenu">Sub Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="submenu">Sub Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="submenu">Sub Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out ... I accepted your answer...  :-)    I am impressed by the fact that you have managed to achieve everything in CSS -- with only minimal javascript ... Way to go !!! Muy Obrigado !!!  :-)